# Migrate old Java 8 maven/netbeans project to a modern GraalVM/Java 19 in VScode

Tags: maven, netbeans, java-8, graalvm

I'm studying Visual Studio Code and GraalVM, I have this pack [1] and an old Java 8 project. What is the best way to make VScode/Maven/Netbeans Language Server to compile my project with the latest Java to see what should I fix?

Here's the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vsetec</groupId>
    <artifactId>vsetec-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.sip</groupId>
            <artifactId>jain-sip-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-91</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>Utilities</name>
    <description>Some reusable procedures</description>
</project>
```

Everything is a bit old, so I'm going to make it check against the modern Java and fix dependencies one by one, but I'm guessing the "compiler source and target" are already an obsolete Maven plugin configurations. Any tips?

[1] https://www.graalvm.org/latest/tools/vscode/graalvm-extension-pack/

Comment: You have too many things you change at once. Start with making what you have work with Java 19 from the command line.

Comment: You're right, though I've managed to compile my thing with GraalVM in Netbeans and now resolving the ScriptEngine issues which would be much harder in the new environment

Comment: _"What is the best way..."_ and _"Any tips?"_ are red flags that your question is probably off topic for SO, since this is not a help/discussion forum for general advice and assistance. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Can you reframe your question so that it conforms to SO guidelines? The most important point is that your question should be asking about an actual problem that you have encountered, rather than inviting opinions and advice on how to proceed.

Comment: @skomisa, you must be right but I'm even struggling to ask a correct question. As I'm currently proceeding in Netbeans, the platform may remove my question if there is no value in it and there are no people in the world that are thinking to switch to VScode, have no-one around to ask in person and seeking the offtopic advice to proceed